# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.negateNode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm currently working on a Java EE project which uses JPA. I'm connecting to a InnuDB MySQL DB and after having some problems with some entities relations (ManyToMany) I changed some of the  Collection structures to Set and the error dissapeared(As I saw in other posts) however now I'm having this error after the JDNI load the databases.

This is the structure I had to change in several parts of my project:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Tema> temas;
```

This is the Tema Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tema",
uniqueConstraints =
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nombreTema"}))
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name = "darTemas",
    query = "SELECT sct FROM Tema sct"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "darTemaPorNombre",
    query = "SELECT sct FROM Tema sct WHERE sct.nombreTema = :nombreSct")
})
public class Tema implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    /**
     * El id del tema
     */

    private Long id;
    /**
     * El nombre del tema
     */
    @Column(name = "nombreTema")
    private String nombreTema;

    /*@Basic(optional = false)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Area area;*/

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Getters y Setters
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String getNombreTema() {
        return nombreTema;
    }

    public void setNombreTema(String nombreTema) {
        this.nombreTema = nombreTema;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Tema)) {
            return false;
        }
        Tema other = (Tema) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + ";" + nombreTema;
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I run the project.

```
 INFO [httpWorkerThread-4848-0] (SchemaUpdate.java:160) - schema update complete
 INFO [httpWorkerThread-4848-0] (NamingHelper.java:26) - JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
ERROR [httpWorkerThread-4848-0] (ErrorCounter.java:33) - line 1:12: unexpected token: FROM
The log message is null.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.negateNode(HqlParser.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2378)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2331)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2296)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2082)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2249)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1455)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1365)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1106)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:702)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:159)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:402)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:149)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:84)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.loadPersistenceUnits(AbstractLoader.java:915)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.doLoad(ApplicationLoader.java:184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:126)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.doLoad(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:240)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:336)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:210)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:645)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeApplicationDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:959)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleApplicationDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:943)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:467)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:609)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:653)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.start(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:773)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:390)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:373)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90)
        at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304)
        at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:170)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.callers.InvokeCaller.call(InvokeCaller.java:69)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.MBeanServerRequestHandler.handle(MBeanServerRequestHandler.java:155)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.processRequest(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:122)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.doPost(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:193)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:117)
Input stream has been finalized or forced closed without being explicitly closed; stream instantiation reported in following stack trace
java.lang.Throwable
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader$SentinelInputStream.<init>(EJBClassLoader.java:1166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader$InternalJarURLConnection.getInputStream(EJBClassLoader.java:1259)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:433)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:468)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:283)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1040)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:838)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:601)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:333)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:307)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:130)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:149)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:84)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.loadPersistenceUnits(AbstractLoader.java:915)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.doLoad(ApplicationLoader.java:184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:126)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.doLoad(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:240)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:336)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:210)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:645)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeApplicationDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:959)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleApplicationDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:943)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:467)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:609)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:653)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.start(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:773)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:390)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:373)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90)
        at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304)
        at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:170)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.callers.InvokeCaller.call(InvokeCaller.java:69)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.MBeanServerRequestHandler.handle(MBeanServerRequestHandler.java:155)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.processRequest(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:122)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.doPost(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:193)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:117)
CORE5021: NO se cargó la aplicación:
```

Any clue where the error can be?

Comment: solved without an accepted answer? then delete question please else it keeps showing up, thx

Comment: @Jorge, if you are satisfied with the solution, please post it as an answer and click the green outlined checkmark next to it so that others can benefit from your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me with this, and got it solved, the problem apparently was the named query, I moved the query to the method calling it, instead of using the named query, and it solved, its really weird, considering the query is the same.

```
public Collection<Tema> darTemas() {
    Query nq = em.createQuery("SELECT sct FROM Tema sct");
    return nq.getResultList();
}
```